# How to get VM details from Azure Rate-API metadata

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

i am trying to get exhaustive list of all Azure Services available in sub and its pricing using RATE API.
I wanted to confirm if the RATE API will return VM details like, size, core, RAM etc.
 "D1: 1 cores, 3.5 GB RAM, 50 GB disk"

Currently the EA portal which is based on billing API i believe return just the VM type:
1 standard virtual machine(s), d1v2 size: 744 hours

Can someone confirm if RATE api will return the VM details as well?

thanks

Comment: I don't have any experience using this API however, if you take a look at http://azureprice.net you will see that they are listing the VM name, Core, Memory, but I don't see storage.

If you go to the 'About' page, they list Azure Billing API as their source for the VM sizes and pricing: http://azureprice.net/Home/About

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RateCard API doesn't return VM details. However, you can use this API -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-list-sizes-region. Unfortunately, there is no common column/key for you to join the responses from the two APIs.